# Can't format pen driver of 16GB, it just show 4.1GB

Tags: linux, ubuntu, format, partition, usb-drive

After create a bootable disk, I can't format my pendrive, I use the command

"sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb bs=512 count=1" and after that, it just shows 4.1GB instead of 16GB. The Gparted just shows 4GB too and I can not erase or create a partition table from it. The Disc utility from Ubuntu gives me an error if I try format the pendrive. What can I do to get the real size of my pendrive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`blockdev --getsize64 /dev/sdb` will print device size in bytes.  See [the man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/blockdev.8.html).

Comment: It gives me the size but how can I format it?

Comment: What does `sudo fdisk -l` give you?

Comment: It gives me this:

Comment: Disk /dev/sdb: 15,7 GiB, 16840130560 bytes, 32890880 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Comment: That looks good to me.  Partition and format it.  See: http://www.howtogeek.com/106873/how-to-use-fdisk-to-manage-partitions-on-linux/